# django rest framework - always INSERTs, never UPDATES

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to UPDATE a user record by POST. However, the id is always NULL. Even if I pass the id it seems to be ignored

View Code:

JSON POSTED:

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Craig Champion", 
    "profession": "Developer", 
    "email": "craig@isai.co.uk"
}

@api_view(['POST'])
def get_purchase(request):
    """
    Gets purchase records for a user

    Purchase collection is returned
    """

    user = User();
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)

    if serializer.is_valid():

       #The object ALWAYS has ID = nothing at this point

        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,   status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

ModelSerializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'profession', 'email', 'password', )
        write_only_fields = ('password' , )
```

Model

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can I force the savechanges to update and see the ID?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `partial=True` to update a row with partial data:

```
serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
```

From [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#deserializing-objects):

> By default, serializers must be passed values for all required fields
>   or they will throw validation errors. You can use the `partial` argument
>   in order to allow partial updates.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. the issue is that when I initialise UserSerializer the id is not passed into the object. It is always Nothing (or null)

Comment: @ISAIMobile By calling `User()` you're creating a new user object. To update an already present user fetch that user using a `User.objects.get` query first and then pass that to the serializer with `partial=True`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I extract the id of the user from request.DATA?

Comment: @ISAIMobile `request.DATA['id']` should do it.