# Django rest framework not reading JSON right

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I am using a basic API view as such:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def load_info(request,user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    profile = user.profile
    serialized = ProfileSerializerInfo(profile,data=request.DATA)
    print serialized.data
    if serialized.is_valid():
        return Response(serialized)
    else:
        return Response(serialized.errors)
```

now the `print serialized.data` returns the full amount of information **with a user**, yet the JSON returned is the `serialized.errors`, which says:

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

why is Django rest framework not noticing the user field in the JSON?

## Note

this is what `serialized.data` looks like:

```
{'user': {u'id': 22, ...}, 'follower_count':3452,...}
```

I also tried passing `serialized.data` to `Response`, but that did not work either.

by request, here is the serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializerInfo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you post the definition of ProfileSerializerInfo and are you using nested serializers?

You could try user = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False) on ProfileSerializerInfo

Also found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412324/django-rest-framework-always-inserts-never-updates?rq=1):

You need to use `partial=True` to update a row with partial data:

```
serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
```

From [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#deserializing-objects):

> By default, serializers must be passed values for all required fields
>   or they will throw validation errors. You can use the `partial` argument
>   in order to allow partial updates.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just needed to add `partial=True` as a param when I call the profile serializer